# Theme Check: Could not find post_class

Tags: theme-development, themes, debug, post-class

I've inherited a theme from a another developer that I've re-styled for a client. We're just about finished, but I thought I'd run it through the Theme-Check plug-in to see if there's any errors or problems.

Unfortunately there's a ton. I've gotten rid of most of them, but I have one Required left:

```
REQUIRED: Could not find post_class. See: post_class
```

I've read the WP page on post_class, but as a relative newcomer I still don't understand what it is, or why it should be *required*.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: If the Theme isn't intended for public distribution, then many of the **required** components of Theme Check will not apply. The `post_class()` requirement is one of them.

Comment: @ChipBennett Thanks, Chip. I'll bear that in mind. Probably good practice if the client adds plug-ins themselves in the future, though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What it does

[`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) adds classes to the posts on a post by post basis, usually adding them to some kind of post "wrapper". This allows for the targeting of posts with CSS rules according to various criteria-- category, tag, sticky, format, etc. That is, theme authors, plugin authors, and individual users can write CSS rules based on the classes added by [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) and get very fine grained control over layout.

### Why you want it

While I am not a canonical source, I am sure it is required according to the WordPress Theme guidelines to ensure a minimal functionality across themes. If you aren't submitting your theme to the WordPress repo you can do what you want. There are no WordPress Theme Police to track you down and spank you, but [`post_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) and the related [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) are very useful and easy to implement. I see no reason not to use them.

Comment: Thanks very much! That helps a lot. In my case, though, there's no different styles for different posts, so I suppose it's not very much use to me?

Comment: There may be no styling for posts right now, but you don't know about later, and you don't know what a plugin might try to do. It is reasonable for a plugin to depend upon officially required functionality.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm going to add it.